# Localized index for UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, localization, indexing

I'm trying to use a localized index for my UITableView same as iPhone's Contacts application . here is how I return an array of characters:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];
}
```

I changed the language setting to a non-English (Ex: Russian). However, it always returns an array of character in English:

|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|#

It is unlike the iPhone Contacts application which shows the index with merged Russian and English characters.

Is there anyway to get the localized array of characters?

Comment: I found the solution! In order to get localized table index using above API, your application should provide the corresponding localization language.

Comment: How do you provide the localization language for the application?

Comment: yes, how do you provide localization ?

Comment: in Xcode, go to your Project(in project navigator), in the Info tab you will see list of all Location Languages which you can add/remove to. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CLDR's 'index characters' as I described here:  [C#: get letters of alphabet for scandinavian language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542781)
That function probably does the same internally, or it wants to.