# Cocoa method to return a list of all letters in the current locale's alphabet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

I'm currently trying to implement a [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [data source](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDatasource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that replicates, as closely as possible, the functionality found the [`ABAddressBookUI`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Framework/index.html) framework's [`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, but with the added ability to select multiple contacts at once (as indicated by adding/removing an accessory view to the appropriate [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Everything is working fine, with the exception of providing localized "section index titles" (the letters that appear in the scroll overlay to the right of the screen) for the [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as should be returned by the [data source](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDatasource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:) method:

> `- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

Obviously, I could just return an [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) containing the [`NSStrings`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) A, B, C ...Z, but I'd ideally like this method to return an array of all of the (uppercase, where applicable) letters of the alphabet **of the current locale**.

One promising lead was:

> `[[`[`NSLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html)`currentLocale ] objectForKey:@"NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet" ]`

But I can't find any significant documentation on this and it returns an [`NSCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), from which I've been unable to extract the actual characters (if I could do that, then NSCharacterSet's [`capitalizedLetterCharacterSet`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/capitalizedLetterCharacterSet) could also be a promising starting point).

I've also run an [`otool -tV`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html) on the [`AddressBookUI`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/addressbookui/reference/addressbookui_framework/index.html) framework, which revealed a call to the function `ABAddressBookCopySectionIndices()`, into which an [`ABAddressBookRef`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) can be passed to obtain exactly what I'm looking for… a CFArray of the localized alphabet. *However*, it's a private function, so I can't use it in my app.

So, does anybody know whether Cocoa Touch supports this functionality? And, if not, are there any ideas as to how `ABAddressBookCopyIndices()` is working its magic? I suspect the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) library may well hold the key, but I'm not (as yet) familiar with its capabilities...

Comment: Another way to log a character set

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804270/how-to-print-characterset-in-objective-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please don't assume that the section indices should be "capital letters". That's only valid for some European languages. E.g. Japanese or Chinese don't have the concept of capital letters, they just have too many letters to start with, but there's a customary set of labels usually used in real-world dictionaries or real-world address books.

Instead, use the standard [UILocalizedIndexedCollation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html). It gives exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks very much, Yuji! I can't believe I didn't find that class earlier. I Googled so many different phrases to try to find this, but I guess "collation" was the one I needed. I'm aware that capital letters don't exist in a number of languages, which was why I put uppercase in parentheses in the original post. I've now edited it to make that a little clearer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're perfectly welcome :) Please make an app which nicely works in any language!

Comment: But now I found this worrying post in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909084/localized-index-for-uitableview 
Apparently the method is there, but was not implemented correctly yet. Gosh.

Comment: Good find. In that case, there's maybe something more sophisticated going on in ABAddressBookCopySectionIndices(), as I can NSLog() the returned array and it matches exactly what's displayed in the system Address Book. I'll have a play around with UILocalizedIndexedCollation tomorrow and report back (as I guess there's a chance this was fixed in iOS 4).

If only we were allowed to use the private APIs!

Comment: That function probably uses CLDR's 'index characters' as I described here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542781

Answer (score 5):

Got bored and wrote this up for you

```
NSArray * charactersInCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet *charSet)
{
  NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSData * data = [charSet bitmapRepresentation];
  const char* bytes = [data bytes];

  for (int i = 0; i < 8192; ++i)
  {
    if (bytes[i >> 3] & (((unsigned int)1) << (i & 7)))
    {
      [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", i]];
    }
  }
  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}

NSCharacterSet * charSet = [[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"sr_Cyrl_ME"] autorelease] objectForKey:NSLocaleExemplarCharacterSet];
NSArray * chars = charactersInCharacterSet(charSet);
for (NSString *str in chars)
{
  NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

That will give you an array of the characters in the set.

Comment: Please have mercy to East Asians and don't use that :p  It'll give a list of thousands of letters, with widely different usage frequencies; if you take every 100th element as the section title, that will select only a very rarely used characters and that'll be totally useless.

Comment: I didn't really answer the "true" question here. But I answered his subquestion. Your answer is definitely more to the point of what he needs.

Comment: Thanks very much, Josh! Excellent work there. I upvoted this because I'd say it provides some extremely useful functionality, but I hope you don't mind me accepting Yuji's answer instead, as it answers the main question perfectly.

Comment: No problems :) I actually did some more testing and this fails pretty badly on things like asian character sets. Tried it with a japanese locale and got an empty set back. Would need some love to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

this one help you to get what exactly you want

```
let currentCollation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
print(currentCollation)
```