# how to print characterSet in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, nscharacterset

i'm using GNUstep shell for programming objective-c. I'm able to convert string to a character set. But unable to print the converted character set in the console. Please tell me a way to print it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18):

This will do the first 65536 characters in unicode, which will do for most situations.  I believe unicode can go much higher (2^32?), but this would take much longer to log.

```
+ (void) logCharacterSet:(NSCharacterSet*)characterSet
{
    unichar unicharBuffer[20];
    int index = 0;

    for (unichar uc = 0; uc < (0xFFFF); uc ++)
    {
        if ([characterSet characterIsMember:uc])
        {
            unicharBuffer[index] = uc;

            index ++;

            if (index == 20)
            {
                NSString * characters = [NSString stringWithCharacters:unicharBuffer length:index];
                NSLog(@"%@", characters);

                index = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    if (index != 0)
    {
        NSString * characters = [NSString stringWithCharacters:unicharBuffer length:index];
        NSLog(@"%@", characters);
    }
}
```

There are some quite fun looking results, for example here is a sample of 20 characters from `punctuationCharacterSet`.

> ༅༆༇༈༉༊་༌།༎༏༐༑༒༔༺༻༼༽྅