# How to get localized alphabet Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’m translating my app to different languages, how could I get the alphabet based on the localization? Could be Latin, Cyrillic, etc.

Comment: Does this your answere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3161573/14733292

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, but please provide additional information if you believe it isn't covered by that answer. In particular, how is this related to translation? What should this return for non-alphabetic languages? What should this return for English (are "a" and "A" different letters)? What should this return for Arabic (is "ء" a letter)? Could you give a few examples of what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import UIKit // Or Foundation


if let alphabetCharacterSet = Locale(identifier: "ru").exemplarCharacterSet?.intersection(CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters) {
    print(alphabetCharacterSet.characters().sorted(by: {String($0).localizedCompare(String($1)) == .orderedAscending }))
}
// If you don't sort alphabetical order is not guaranteed.

extension CharacterSet {
    func characters() -> [Character] {
        // A Unicode scalar is any Unicode code point in the range U+0000 to U+D7FF inclusive or U+E000 to U+10FFFF inclusive.
        return codePoints().compactMap { UnicodeScalar($0) }.map { Character($0) }
    }

    func codePoints() -> [Int] {
        var result: [Int] = []
        var plane = 0
        // following documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1417719-bitmaprepresentation
        for (i, w) in bitmapRepresentation.enumerated() {
            let k = i % 0x2001
            if k == 0x2000 {
                // plane index byte
                plane = Int(w) << 13
                continue
            }
            let base = (plane + k) << 3
            for j in 0 ..< 8 where w & 1 << j != 0 {
                result.append(base + j)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a problem in some languages like Thai it does not show anything and the list of the characters is empty

Comment: As you can see, @SaeedRahmatolahi, the code relies on `Foundation`'s [capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293427-exemplarcharacterset). You should address those issues to Apple, perhaps submit a Radar. Or maybe use some external library.

Comment: @PaulB the problem is not exemplarCharacterSet as I saw the code point function will get some thing and if I change the code of that I can get some of the characters but I am not sure how to do it but that's possible definitely with some changing the function and the libraries that you mentioned may do the same thing as well

Comment: @PaulB this one worked for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71836841/7567902

Comment: You were right, @SaeedRahmatolahi. The problem was because some languages don't have a concept of lowercase/uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide Localizable.strings base file to you project, which consist of your different text for different origins:

Like
for default language:

```
"Hello World!" = "Hello World!";
```

and for like in Latin language:

```
"Hello World!" = "salve mundi!";
```

Comment: I hope this will help in resolving your query, in case of any issue feel free to connect over same.

Comment: Thank you, but I’ve already translate texts with a Localizable.strings. 
I wanted to programatically get alphabet based on localization because I have a view which display all the letter of the alphabet.